# Should you lower the TX Rate on a slow public Wi-Fi?

Tags: wifi-configuration

Im trying to get a 2.4 GHz based public Wi-Fi to work the most optimal way.

The facts I have are these:

- ADSL Connection at 20/20 Mbps.
- 7 access points (2.4 GHz only) with different SSIDs
- There are super many neighbouring APs.
- AP isolation enabled, no local P2P.

These things I can't change but I can make other changes.

I have already limited the channel width and locked the channels on the best frequency plan I possible for the physical layout. So, the own access points are not interfering with each other.

What I'm now thinking about is lowering the TX rate to match the actual maximum speed of the connection.

**Does lowering the TX Rate help with congestion?**

*My phone usually only get 5-20 TX rate which is enough.*

Comment: My completely untrained guess is that you'd get nearly the opposite result, as devices would have to stay "on air" for longer... (Is having different SSIDs really optimal though?)

Comment: @grawity I hoped they'd get a more stable connection. No, I can't change the SSIDs sadly.